# Write an excel or csv file in a way that the dataframes are listed on the same sheet, instead of multiple sheets in R

Tags: r, save

I have an object that contains multiple dataframes and wanted to produce a single excel worksheet with the data. I know there are ways of dealing with this problem in excel. But is there a way to manipulate it from the R side, so that people don't have to worry about the extra steps that weren't in my R script? I have been using this function (see below), but am open to another function. This function produces 1 excel file, but a worksheet for every dataframe. I have 119 dataframes. So this is not really practical.

```
write_xlsx(results1, "hpresponse1.MinimallyAdjusted")
```

I used the bind_rows. However, some of the data was lost. I am not sure how to retain it, especially as I don't even know what kind of data it is. But I turned my results for logistic regression into a dataframe so that I was able to perform certain manipulations. There are labels of some kind off to the left that are not variables. Can I turn these data into a variable so that it is retained when I use bind_rows?

[image: Example of 1 of my dataframes]

Comment: I guess your `results1` object is a list of data frames. In that case you could row bind your datasets into one using e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows(results1)` before exporting to xl.

Answer (score 0):

(Up front, I'm assuming that the 199 frames are all *different*. Or at least that they are structured or used such that you must not combine them into a single frame, as stefan has suggested in the comments.)

I suggest you use the `openxlsx` package and offset each table individually.

```r
L <- list(mtcars[1:3,1:3], mtcars[4:5,1:5], mtcars[6:10,1:4])
wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook("quux.xlsx")
sapply(L, nrow)
# [1] 3 2 5
starts <- cumsum(c(1L, 2L + sapply(L[-length(L)], nrow)))
starts
# [1]  1  6 10

wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, "quuxsheet")
ign <- Map(function(x, st) openxlsx::writeData(wb, sheet = "quuxsheet", x = x, startRow = st), L, starts)
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, file = "quux.xlsx")
```

[image: excel worksheet with three tables, spaced]

- `sapply(L, nrow)` gives us the number of rows in each table in the list. This is used so that we know to offset so-many-rows after a table for the next table. Since we don't care about the number of rows in the last frame, we omit it with `L[-length(L)]`
- `2L + sapply(..)` gives us a gap of 1 row between each frame in the worksheet. Change to to suit your needs.
- `cumsum(c(1L, 2L+sapply(..))` is because we need an absolute row number, not just the counts for each frame. This results in `starts` holding the first excel row number for each frame in `L`.